# How to get the output of the python script executed in aws instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, bash, python, boto

I am trying to automate the aws instance setup using boto. I have a python script in which I will do the ssh to the instance. After ssh,I am executing a python function which is in remote python file using shell command( python -c "filename").I am unable to get the output until the python execution gets complete. How can we get the real time output then and there from the remote python script?

Comment: Are you sure the command outputs anything while it is running?  It may not be flushing its output.

Comment: The python script which I call outputs while running. Is there anyway to flush the output of the python to the shell I call from my local python script?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host "python -c python-script.py"
```